# insert in the head tag after wp_head

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, output-buffering

Using wordpress 2.9.2. I am loading my css files for plugins as they are being called, which ofcourse is after my header has been loaded. I want to insert the calls those css files in the HEAD tag of the page, which can be done if i get a hook which includes lines in the head after wp_head() has been called. Help !

Comment: will you elaborate what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I have my own custom theme, I want my css files to be loaded in the head section of HTML, right now as I call my plugins they add their css files right there in the HTML where they are called, i Want such a hook that integrates those css calls in the HEAD tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was inserting the css files in head using output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head - the action is called wp_head.

You will want to use [wp_register_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) to register your CSS file followed by [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to actually add it to the list of stylesheets that are output.

There is an example on that page, but replace 'wp_print_styles' in the example with 'wp_head'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echoing the styles or .css include the in a function passed into wp_print_styles [API action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own theme, you can just put <style> tags in your header.php file pointing to the stylesheets you are using.

If you need a hook, it is called wp_head (check the Codex documentation on it).